# Sniff outgoing traffic on my server on a SSL channel

Tags: networking, ssl, https, curl, tcpdump

Im executing a CURL command on a php application running on my nginx server (centOS). The end point is a https address so the outgoing traffic is of course encrypted.

I want to see the network packets that are actually getting send to the end point  using [tcpDump](http://www.tecmint.com/12-tcpdump-commands-a-network-sniffer-tool/) to sniff the outgoing traffic. But the result of this is just a bunch of encrypted data.

Is there a way to see this packets before they get encrypted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you control the remote server?

If you have its private key, you can decrypt the HTTPS data in Wireshark (have `tcpdump` write to a file with `-w` then open it in Wireshark).

Otherwise, probably your best bet is to pump your traffic through an HTTPS proxy that can decrypt the data - check out [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp).